# Create cluster by group in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a data with multiple records by ID (and thousands of ID). I want to cluster each ID but taking in to account each record in var1 (I have about 20 variables). The problem is that I don't think taking the average by ID to feed the cluster function is the best way.
An example could be like this data. 3 ID with multiple records of var1.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), var1 = c(100,110,100,200,100, 250, 200,180, 200, 200, 70, 60, 70))
```

If I take the average by ID, `Mclust` will give me 2 group (putting ID1 and ID3 together) but looking at the data, I would have like to have a distinction between ID1 and ID3.
Is it some other function to create a cluster which will do that in R? Kind of like the cluster argument in `coxph()...`
Hope I am clear enough!

Comment: I am not a cluster expert ... however, the function documentation mentions `Mclust(data, G = NULL, ...`, with G An integer vector specifying the numbers of mixture components (clusters) for which the BIC is to be calculated. The default is G=1:9. Thus, I would argue, you can force `G=3:9` to have a minimum of 3 clusters. Good luck!

Comment: I could force it for the example yes but I don't now how many cluster I need regarding 20 variable and thousands of IDs

Comment: Isn't the purpose of cluster experimentation to find the right number of clusters for your analysis? Check out the package `{NbClust}`. It contains 20+ indices and recommends a  number of clusters. There are also options to choose the clustering method/type.

Comment: Are you looking for clusters within each ID or across IDs?

Comment: I want that each ID belong to a cluster. Even if I force `Mclust` to make 3 group the third group is empty because ID1 and ID3 have the same mean (even if the variance between sample is different).